# How to support UTF-8 on Windows without using "chcp 65001" command in C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, gbk

I want to support UTF-8 string in my program, but the default active code page is 936.

Is there any methods to support UTF-8 without using the `chcp 65001` command?

And the `std::locale` doesn't seem to work, it always throws an error when I'm using `std::locale::global(std::locale("zh_CN.UTF-8"));`:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

int main() {
  std::wstring a = L"中文字符串"; // a chinese string.

  using cvt = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
  std::wstring_convert<cvt, wchar_t> converter;

  std::string x = converter.to_bytes(a);

  std::cout << x << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output without `"chcp 65001"`:

```
涓枃瀛楃涓
```

Output with `"chcp 65001"`:

```
Active code page: 65001
中文字符串
```

I don't want to use the "chcp 65001" command and don't want to see the prompt.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'support'?

Comment: to use the UTF-8 string

Comment: Use it how?  Please post some representative code, see [mre].

Comment: sorry, i'm new. I'll edit it.

Comment: No worries, take your time

Comment: I have finished editing the question

Comment: Thanks. chcp is required, AFAIK, but I believe you can run it once, for any console session, and it will 'stick'.  Also, you should be able to redirect its output (to NUL:) to get rid of the prompt.

Comment: Well, OK, there might be a way, but probably not an easy way.  Check out the WIN32 console APIs.

Comment: Might be able to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, ".utf8");` (Windows 10 build 17134 (April 2018 Update) or later).  [Universal C Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) support for UTF-8.

Comment: @Eljay _think_ the issue is the code page being used by the console, not the runtime.  But don't quote me.

Comment: @PaulSanders • could very well be.  There are a lot of things that need to be set "just so" for UTF-8 to work end-to-end on Windows.  To Microsoft's credit, they have been working to make UTF-8 a "first class citizen" option, rather than a barrier to entry.  (And Microsoft did jump on the Unicode bandwagon as an early adopter, initially supporting UCS-2.)

Comment: "*I don't want to use the "chcp 65001" command*" - use [`SetConsoleOutputCP()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp) instead.