# How can utf-8 input be received in a window procedure?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to convert a C program to use the Windows UTF-8 feature and am having trouble getting it to work properly. The input messages from the window procedure don't seem to receive the correct UTF-8 values. **The question [Windows producing UTF8 sequence for ANSI version WM_CHAR? Why I cannot see it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191880/windows-producing-utf8-sequence-for-ansi-version-wm-char-why-i-cannot-see-it), does not answer my issue. The fix for the Tibetan special case mentioned in that question does not fix the Hebrew and Japanese problems mentioned in my question**.

I have created the console test program below which can be run in UTF-8 (using the A API versions) or Unicode (using the W API versions) modes. The UTF-8 mode is default and displays the values received by the WM_IME_CHAR and WM_CHAR messages in hex. To use the Unicode mode, the letter w is added as a command line argument. The Unicode mode also displays the values received by the WM_IME_CHAR and WM_CHAR messages but additionally displays the UTF-8 value converted from the Unicode (UTF-16LE) value.

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <ime.h>    // for WM_IME_REPORT
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for _countof macro
#include <locale.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );

//                              1         2         3         4         5         6
//                     123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
static char szTop[] = "Message            Key             Char value(s)";
static char szUnd[] = "------------------ --------------- ------------------";
static char *szFormat   = "%-18s %-15.15s\n";
static char *szInputFmt = "%-18s                 0x%p\n";
static char *szInput2Fmt = "                                   %s";
static char *szMsgName[] = {
    "WM_KEYDOWN",    "WM_KEYUP",    // 0x100, 0x101,
    "WM_CHAR",       "WM_DEADCHAR", // 0x102, 0x103,
    "WM_SYSKEYDOWN", "WM_SYSKEYUP", // 0x104, 0x105,
    "WM_SYSCHAR",    "WM_SYSDEADCHAR" };    // 0x106, 0x107

static int Wide = 0;

// UTF-8 bit combinations
// 1 byte:  0xxxxxxx
// 2 bytes: 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
// 3 bytes: 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
// 4 bytes: 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
//
// (single byte, 0xxxxxxxx)
#define UTF8_SINGLE_BYTE(b)     (!((b) & 0x80))
// (first byte, 11xxxxxx)
#define UTF8_FIRST_BYTE(b)      (0xC0 == ((b) & 0xC0))
// (continuation byte, 10xxxxxx)
#define UTF8_CONTINUATION_BYTE(b)   (0x80 == ((b) & 0xC0))

static HWND createWindowA()
{
    DWORD err;

    // Register window class

    WNDCLASSA   WindowClass;
    WindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.hInstance = (HINSTANCE)NULL;
    WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIconA( NULL, (LPCSTR)IDI_APPLICATION );
    WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursorA( NULL, (LPCSTR)IDC_ARROW );
    WindowClass.hbrBackground = GetStockObject( WHITE_BRUSH );
    WindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = "MY_CLASS";
    if (!RegisterClassA( &WindowClass )) {
        err = GetLastError();
        printf( "RegisterClass() Error= 0x%08x, %d\n", err, err );
        return NULL;
    }

    // create window

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowA(
        "MY_CLASS",     /* window class name */
        "UTF-8 Keyboard Message Viewer",/* window name */
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,   /* initial position */
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,   /* size (w, h) */
        NULL, NULL,         /* parent, menu */
        (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandleA( NULL ),
        NULL );
    if (!hwnd) {
        err = GetLastError();
        printf( "CreateWindow() Error= 0x%08x, %d\n", err, err );
        return NULL;
    }

    return hwnd;
}

static HWND createWindowW()
{
    DWORD err;

    // Register window class

    WNDCLASSW   WindowClass;
    WindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.hInstance = (HINSTANCE)NULL;
    WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIconW( NULL, (LPCWSTR)IDI_APPLICATION );
    WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursorW( NULL, (LPCWSTR)IDC_ARROW );
    WindowClass.hbrBackground = GetStockObject( WHITE_BRUSH );
    WindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = L"MY_CLASS";
    if (!RegisterClassW( &WindowClass )) {
        err = GetLastError();
        printf( "RegisterClass() Error= 0x%08x, %d\n", err, err );
        return NULL;
    }

    // create window

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        L"MY_CLASS",        /* window class name */
        L"UTF-8 Keyboard Message Viewer",/* window name */
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,   /* initial position */
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,   /* size (w, h) */
        NULL, NULL,         /* parent, menu */
        (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandleW( NULL ),
        NULL );
    if (!hwnd) {
        err = GetLastError();
        printf( "CreateWindowExW() Error= 0x%08x, %d\n", err, err );
        return NULL;
    }

    return hwnd;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    HWND hwnd = NULL;

    SetConsoleOutputCP( CP_UTF8 );
    Wide = ((argc > 1) && ('w' == *argv[1] || 'W' == *argv[1]));

    if (Wide) {
        hwnd = createWindowW(); // Unicode version
    }
    else {
        hwnd = createWindowA(); // Multi-byte version
    }
    if (!hwnd) {
        printf( "Failed to register Window Class.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    wchar_t locale_name[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
                /* get the current input language and territory */
    int ret = LCIDToLocaleName((LCID)LOWORD(GetKeyboardLayout(0)),
            locale_name,
            LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH, 0);
    if (!ret) {
        printf( "LCIDToLocaleName, error=%d\n", GetLastError() );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    // Get the locale information
    wchar_t locale_lc_ctype[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH + 6];// locale + encoding
    wcsncpy_s( locale_lc_ctype, _countof(locale_lc_ctype),
        locale_name, _TRUNCATE );
    wcscat_s( locale_lc_ctype, _countof(locale_lc_ctype), L".utf8" );

    // Set the CRT locale
    wchar_t *pclocale = _wsetlocale( LC_CTYPE, locale_lc_ctype );
    printf( "setlocale() %S\n\n", pclocale );

    printf( "%s\n", szTop );
    printf( "%s\n", szUnd );

    ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
    UpdateWindow( hwnd );

    MSG msg;
    if (Wide) {
        while (GetMessageW( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessageW( &msg );
        }
    }
    else {
        while (GetMessageA( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessageA( &msg );
        }
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;  // WM_QUIT
}

// Figure out how many bytes in this UTF-8 character
// 
// High 4 bits of 1st UTF-8 byte:
//   0xxx (length = 1)
//   110x (12 or 13 -> length = 2)
//   1110 (14 -> length = 3)
//   1111 (15 -> length = 4)
static int get_utf8len( unsigned char firstByte )
{
    int len;

    if (UTF8_SINGLE_BYTE(firstByte)) {
        // Single byte UTF-8 character
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (!UTF8_FIRST_BYTE(firstByte)) {
        // Invalid UTF-8 1st byte
        return -1;
    }

    // Mask off high 4 bits and shift them to the low 4 bits
    len = (firstByte & 0xF0) >> 4;

    // Subtracting 11 will give us the number of bytes for
    // two of the cases
    len -= 11;

    // The last case will have a value of 1 or 2, both of
    // these cases indicate a length of 2. Change 1 to 2.
    if (len < 2) {
        len = 2;
    }

    return len;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    static int surrogate_count = 0;
    static int mbIndex = 0; // multi-byte index
    static int mbLen = 0;   // multi-byte length
    static wchar_t utf16_char[3];   // NULL terminated UTF-16
    static char utf8_char[5];   // NULL terminated UTF-8
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    char szKeyName[32];

    utf16_char[2] = L'\0';  // NULL terminate all supplementary UTF-16 characters

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_SIZE:   // 0x5
        InvalidateRect( hwnd, NULL, TRUE );
        return 0;

        // MESSAGES TO REPORT
    case WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE:    // 0x51
    {
        wchar_t szLocaleName[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
        HKL hkl = (HKL)lParam;
        LANGID langId = LOWORD(HandleToUlong(hkl));
        LCID lcid = MAKELCID(langId, SORT_DEFAULT);
        LCIDToLocaleName( lcid, szLocaleName, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH,
            LOCALE_ALLOW_NEUTRAL_NAMES );

        wchar_t locale_lc_ctype[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH + 6];// locale + encoding
        wcsncpy_s( locale_lc_ctype, _countof(locale_lc_ctype),
            szLocaleName, _TRUNCATE );
        wcscat_s( locale_lc_ctype, _countof(locale_lc_ctype), L".utf8" );

        // set the C runtime locale
        wchar_t *pclocale = _wsetlocale( LC_CTYPE, locale_lc_ctype );

        printf( "\nWM_INPUTLANGCHANGE 0x%08x 0x%08x=(%S)\n",
            (DWORD)wParam, lcid, szLocaleName );
        printf( "setlocale() %S\n\n", pclocale );
        printf( "%s\n", szTop );
        printf( "%s\n", szUnd );
        return TRUE;
    }

        // KEYBOARD MESSAGES
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    case WM_KEYUP:
    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
    case WM_SYSKEYUP:
        GetKeyNameTextA( (LONG)lParam, szKeyName, _countof(szKeyName) );
        printf( szFormat,
            szMsgName[message - WM_KEYFIRST],   // 1
            szKeyName );                // 2

        break;      // call DefWindowProc so Sys messages work

        // INPUT MESSAGES
    case WM_CHAR:
    case WM_DEADCHAR:
    case WM_SYSCHAR:
    case WM_SYSDEADCHAR:
        printf( szInputFmt,
            szMsgName[message - WM_KEYFIRST],   // 1
            wParam );               // 2 [character value(s)]

        if (WM_CHAR == message) {
            if (!Wide) {
                // HANDLE UTF-8 byte(s) in wParam

                char *utf8 = (char *)&wParam;
                if (0 == mbIndex) {
                    // This should be the 1st byte.

                    // get the number of bytes in this character
                    mbLen = get_utf8len( utf8[0] );
                    if (mbLen < 0) {
                        printf( "ERROR: Invalid UTF-8 1st byte = %02x\n",
                            (int)(unsigned char)utf8[0] );
                        mbIndex = 0;
                        mbLen = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        // save this byte
                        utf8_char[0] = utf8[0];
                        mbIndex += 1;

                        // SPECIAL CASE: Handle more than one UTF-8 byte from wParam.
                        // 
                        // save the remaining bytes from wParam
                        for (int i = 1; (i < mbLen) && (utf8[mbIndex] != '\0'); ++i) {
                            utf8_char[mbIndex] = utf8[mbIndex++];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (!UTF8_CONTINUATION_BYTE(utf8[0])) {
                    // Invalid continuation byte

                    printf( "ERROR: Resetting, invalid UTF-8 byte = %02x\n",
                        (int)(unsigned char)utf8[0] );
                    mbIndex = 0;
                    mbLen = 0;
                }
                else if (mbIndex < mbLen) {
                    // Save continuation byte

                    utf8_char[mbIndex++] = utf8[0];
                }
                else if (mbIndex > mbLen) {
                    // Invalid number of UTF-8 bytes

                    printf( "ERROR: Resetting, too many bytes received = %d\n",
                        mbIndex + 1 );
                    mbIndex = 0;
                    mbLen = 0;
                }

                if ((mbLen != 0) &&(mbLen == mbIndex)) {
                    // Finished with this character
                    utf8_char[mbLen] = '\0';    // NULL terminate

                    // display the hex bytes and character
                    printf( szInput2Fmt, "UTF-8: " );
                    for (int i = 0; i < mbLen; ++i) {
                        printf( "0x%02x ", (int)(unsigned char)utf8_char[i] );
                    }
                    printf( "\n" );
                    printf( szInput2Fmt, "CHAR:  " );
                    printf( "\"%s\"\n", utf8_char );

                    mbLen = 0;
                    mbIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            else {  // wide char (UTF-16)
                wchar_t wchar = (wchar_t)wParam;

                // handle UTF-16 surrogates

                if (IS_HIGH_SURROGATE(wchar)) {
                    utf16_char[0] = wchar;
                    surrogate_count += 1;
                }
                else if (IS_LOW_SURROGATE(wchar)) {
                    utf16_char[1] = wchar;
                    surrogate_count += 1;
                }
                else {
                    // normal UTF-16 character
                    utf16_char[0] = wchar;
                    utf16_char[1] = L'\0';
                    surrogate_count = 0;
                }

                if (surrogate_count > 1) {
                    if (!IS_SURROGATE_PAIR(utf16_char[0], utf16_char[1])) {
                        // error
                        printf( "Surrogate pair error H:%02x L:%02x\n",
                            (int)(unsigned short)utf16_char[0],
                            (int)(unsigned short)utf16_char[1] );
                        printf( "Surrogate error\n" );
                        surrogate_count = 0;

                        return 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (1 == surrogate_count) {
                    // don't have a full character yet
                    return 0;
                }

                // Received a complete character

                // Display UTF-16
                printf( szInput2Fmt, "UTF-16: " );
                if (surrogate_count) {
                    printf( "0x%02x%02x\n",
                        (int)(unsigned short)utf16_char[0],
                        (int)(unsigned short)utf16_char[1] );
                }
                else {
                    printf( "0x%02x\n", (int)(unsigned short)utf16_char[0] );
                }

                // Convert to UTF-8
                int len = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, utf16_char, -1, utf8_char,
                                _countof(utf8_char), NULL, NULL );
                if (!len) {
                    printf( "WideCharToMultiByte error = %x\n", GetLastError() );
                }

                // Display UTF-8
                printf( szInput2Fmt, "UTF-8:  ");
                for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; ++i) {
                    printf( "0x%02x ", (int)(unsigned char)utf8_char[i] );
                }
                printf( "\n" );
                printf( szInput2Fmt, "CHAR: " );
                printf( "\"%s\"\n", utf8_char );

                // cleanup
                surrogate_count = 0;
            } // end if (Wide)

            return 0;   // WM_CHAR was processed
        } // end if (WM_CHAR == message)
        break;      // call DefWindowProc so WM_SYS* messages work

    case WM_IME_CHAR:
        printf( szInputFmt,
            "WM_IME_CHAR",              // 1
            wParam );               // 2 [character value(s)]
        break;      // call DefWindowProc so we'll get WM_CHAR messages

    case WM_IME_REPORT:
        printf( szInputFmt,
            "WM_IME_REPORT",            // 1
            wParam );               // 2 [IR_STRINGEX = 0x180]
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:  // 0xF
        hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );
        EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:    // 0x2
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        return 0;
    }

    if (Wide) {
        return DefWindowProcW( hwnd, message, wParam, lParam );
    }
    else {
        return DefWindowProcA( hwnd, message, wParam, lParam );
    }
}
```

The program project property "Configuration Properties", "Advanced", "Character Set" in Visual Studio was set to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set". A manifest file was used to set the process ACP to utf-8 (65001) which bypasses the need to select the utf-8 beta option under "Administrative language setting", "Language for non-Unicode programs" and reboot. Information on specifying UTF-8 in an application manifest can be found at [Use UTF-8 code pages in Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page).

I have tested an emoji, Tibetan, Hebrew and Japanese with both the UTF-8 mode and Unicode mode running on Windows 11, 64 bit. **With the input language set to Tibetan, the keys "Q" and "W" were pressed like the example in [Windows producing UTF8 sequence for ANSI version WM_CHAR? Why I cannot see it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191880/windows-producing-utf8-sequence-for-ansi-version-wm-char-why-i-cannot-see-it). This Tibetan case is handled fine, but the problem I am having still occurs.**. For Hebrew, I tried the characters Alef and He which are the keys "T" and "V" respectively. The Hebrew keyboard layout is at [Microsoft keyboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/globalization/keyboards/kbdheb.html). With the input language set to Japanese, the IME option was switched to あ then the "A" key was typed and then the character あ was clicked in the IME.

Here is the output for the updated program running in UTF-8 mode. I am not listing the output for running in UTF-16 mode since it works properly. You can see that the Hebrew and Japanese characters are not correct for UTF-8.

```
setlocale() en-US.utf8

Message            Key             Char value(s)
------------------ --------------- ------------------
WM_KEYDOWN         A
WM_CHAR                            0x0000000000000061
                                   UTF-8: 0x61
                                   CHAR:  "a"
WM_KEYUP           A
WM_KEYDOWN         Left Windows
WM_KEYUP           .
WM_IME_CHAR                        0x00000000000000F0
WM_IME_CHAR                        0x000000000000009F
WM_IME_CHAR                        0x0000000000000098
WM_IME_CHAR                        0x000000000000008A
WM_CHAR                            0x00000000000000F0
WM_CHAR                            0x000000000000009F
WM_CHAR                            0x0000000000000098
WM_CHAR                            0x000000000000008A
                                   UTF-8: 0xf0 0x9f 0x98 0x8a
                                   CHAR:  ""

WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE 0x00000000 0x00000451=(bo-CN)
setlocale() bo-CN.utf8

Message            Key             Char value(s)
------------------ --------------- ------------------
WM_KEYDOWN         Q
WM_CHAR                            0x000000000085BDE0
                                   UTF-8: 0xe0 0xbd 0x85
                                   CHAR:  "ཅ"
WM_KEYUP           Q
WM_KEYDOWN         W
WM_CHAR                            0x000000000086BDE0
                                   UTF-8: 0xe0 0xbd 0x86
                                   CHAR:  "ཆ"
WM_KEYUP           W

WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE 0x000000b1 0x0000040d=(he-IL)
setlocale() he-IL.utf8

Message            Key             Char value(s)
------------------ --------------- ------------------
WM_KEYUP           Ctrl
WM_KEYDOWN         T
WM_CHAR                            0x00000000000000E0
WM_KEYUP           T
WM_KEYDOWN         V
WM_CHAR                            0x00000000000000E4
ERROR: Resetting, invalid UTF-8 byte = e4
WM_KEYUP           V

WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE 0x00000080 0x00000411=(ja-JP)
setlocale() ja-JP.utf8

Message            Key             Char value(s)
------------------ --------------- ------------------
WM_KEYUP           Ctrl
WM_KEYDOWN         A
WM_KEYUP           A
WM_IME_CHAR                        0x000000000000E381
WM_CHAR                            0x0000000000004581
ERROR: Invalid UTF-8 1st byte = 81
WM_CHAR                            0x0000000000004581
ERROR: Invalid UTF-8 1st byte = 81
```

The correct UTF-8 values for the problem cases are:

```
Aleph: 0xd7 0x90
He: 0xd7 0x94
あ: 0xe3 0x81 0x82
```

Is there something I'm missing when using the UTF-8 mode? Are these bugs in the Windows beta UTF-8 implementation? The Microsoft documentation for WM_CHAR states, "the system provides characters in the current process code page, which can be set to UTF-8 in Windows Version 1903 (May 2019 Update) and newer."

### Edit

I have modified the UTF-16 WM_CHAR handling so that it handles surrogates as mentioned by Remy in the comments.

### Edit 10/27/2023

**My test program now handles the Tibetan special case mentioned in that question. That fix does not work for the Hebrew and Japanese problems mentioned. Please explain exactly why this is a duplicate question if you don't agree**.

After looking up different encodings, I found that, in UTF-8 mode, Windows is returning ISO 8859-8 encoded characters for the Hebrew, not UTF-8. In ISO 8859-8, Aleph is 0xE0 and He is 0xE4. For the Japanese characters, The WM_IME_CHAR case seems to have the first two bytes correct, but in reverse order (compared to the Tibetan byte order) and the last byte, 0x82, missing. The Japanese WM_CHAR case seems to have only one byte correct, 0x81. I have not found an encoding that matches what is received for those cases. The updated test program now reports errors for all these cases.

The test program has been updated with the following changes:

1. The console ACP is now set to UTF-8.
2. The C RTL locale is now set for using C functions.
3. UTF-16 surrogate handling has been improved.
4. UTF-8 character parsing has been added to determine invalid characters received.
5. The Tibetan special case is now handled.
6. Characters are now displayed on the console if they are valid.
7. Error messages are displayed for invalid UTF-8 characters.
8. The WM_IME_REPORT case has been added to see if that message is received.

Anyone that has further insight, please comment or post an answer. Hopefully, if this is a bug in the Windows UTF-8 implementation, Microsoft will address it soon!

Comment: One problem I see is in wide mode, you are treating the `wParam` of `WM_CHAR` as a null-terminated string, but it is not. It is a single UTF-16 codeunit instead. And if it carries a UTF-16 surrogate, you won't be able to convert it to UTF-8 from a single message

Comment: FWIW, same for french. This is the same issue as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191880/windows-producing-utf8-sequence-for-ansi-version-wm-char-why-i-cannot-see-it The problem happens in TranslateMessage and I think it's somehow a keyboard (driver) issue

Comment: Your question is similar to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191880/windows-producing-utf8-sequence-for-ansi-version-wm-char-why-i-cannot-see-it?rq=2). For some languages, it is temporarily unable to get UTF8 sequences directly from WM_CHAR.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, you are correct! I will work on fixing that part of the code.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you. I looked at that issue while working on this, but that case was different since the UTF-8 values were there, just in a different way than expected. I could try to deal with special cases like that, but the case I ran into, it doesn't present any correct UTF-8 values (except when doing the conversion explicitly in the Unicode case). Even in the Japanese case, the WM_IME_CHAR does return a partial UTF-8 value, but not the entire value.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Does Microsoft plan to fix this any time soon? It doesn't seem like it would be that difficult to fix. It kind of sounds like I need to go the Unicode route and convert to UTF-8. The software I am converting is multi-platform and we have supported UTF-8 for several years on Linux.

Comment: I'd suggest you submit a feature request about this feature in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select **Developer Platform**-> **API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. After submitting, please click the share button and send me the short link.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Thank you. The problem report link is https://aka.ms/AAlayv6.

Comment: I remember seeing a question a while ago about using UTF-8 with console output (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73246952/how-to-support-utf-8-on-windows-without-using-chcp-65001-command-in-c). Because of that I wondered if the test program might be getting incorrect values because it is a console program. I rewrote the test program to be a windows program instead, but It still received the same, incorrect character values.